# Hello Android OpenCV

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opencv

I went through this tutorial:http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#hello-opencv-sample and it did not go so well. :/

I found the steps confusing and a few spelling errors. Anyway, for instance step 2, "*Set name, target, package and minSDKVersion accordingly. The minimal SDK version for build with OpenCV4Android SDK is 11. Minimal device API Level (for application manifest) is 8*".

I am left wondering what to enter exactly. When I look through the *AndroidManifest.xml* for the *OpenCV Tutorial 1 - Camera Preview Manifest* I see that the minSDKVersion is set as `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />`. This seems to contradict step 2. What am I missing here stackoverflow?

Figure 1 below shows the screen that is causing me my first problems with the 'hello world' OpenCV/Android program.

[image]

Does anyone know of or want to help me create a better hello world android/opencv example?

Regards,

user3870315

Answer (score 0):

Set the minimum required API to 11, and leave the target as 21. If it does not work properly, set the minimum to 9 and try again.

This is just a configuration to be sure your app will be working on old devices.

Comment: What about "Minimum Required SDK" to API 10? I am trying to run this on my Gingerbread device that is at API 10.

Comment: what about the 'Compile With' target?

Comment: I tried to follow these instructions but it did not work until I set the same API level for each option (Minimum Required SDK, Target SDK, Compile With). This solution does not allow me to run the code on my Gingerbread device though. Plus, it seems like something is wrong since the `AndroidManifest.xml` in the example has an API as low as 9. Thanks for the help though El Mynx.